# Create sparse Series of time differences

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe, with one column being a `datetime64[ns]`, and other value columns.
e.g.

```
 df=
      Date                          Value 
    0 2015-03-25 12:50:37.000000      9.4      
    1 2015-03-25 12:52:20.000000        5       
    2 2015-03-25 12:52:30.000000        8
```

I would like to populate another pandas series, which contains regularly spaced indexes as in

```
    myseries=pd.Series(index=pd.date_range(start=time_start, end=time_end, freq='1s',closed='left'))
```

The content of this series should be:
time from last event in df for that timestamp

example:

```
2015-03-25 12:50:37.000000    0 seconds
2015-03-25 12:50:38.000000    1 seconds
2015-03-25 12:50:39.000000    2 seconds
....
2015-03-25 12:52:19.000000    102 seconds
2015-03-25 12:52:20.000000    0 seconds
```

Comment: Will the time difference always be positive? Why is the time difference `0 seconds` in the last two rows of your second and third examples, but the difference between rows equal to `1 seconds` in the first three rows of said examples?

Comment: You are right, I am correcting the desired output

Comment: the time difference should alwas be positive. However, Date could be non uniformly sampled (as in the example)

Comment: @ErroriSalvo Do you need one or many such series? Like you would also need one from `12:52:20.000000` to `12:52:30.000000` ?

Comment: ideally just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reindex with date_range and then cumsum non nan values. With a combination of groupby and cumcount you get your result. I shortened the length of the timewindow for better display.

```
df
                 Date  Value
0 2015-03-25 12:50:17    9.4
1 2015-03-25 12:50:20    5.0
2 2015-03-25 12:50:25    8.0

df = df.set_index(['Date'])
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start='2015-03-25 12:50:17', end='2015-03-25 12:50:25', freq='1s',closed='left'))

                     Value
2015-03-25 12:50:17    9.4
2015-03-25 12:50:18    NaN
2015-03-25 12:50:19    NaN
2015-03-25 12:50:20    5.0
2015-03-25 12:50:21    NaN
2015-03-25 12:50:22    NaN
2015-03-25 12:50:23    NaN
2015-03-25 12:50:24    NaN
2015-03-25 12:50:25    8.0

result = (~df['Value'].isnull()).cumsum()
result = result.groupby(result).cumcount()
2015-03-25 12:50:17    0
2015-03-25 12:50:18    1
2015-03-25 12:50:19    2
2015-03-25 12:50:20    0
2015-03-25 12:50:21    1
2015-03-25 12:50:22    2
2015-03-25 12:50:23    3
2015-03-25 12:50:24    4
2015-03-25 12:50:25    0
Freq: S, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move copy `Date` to your index (keeping the `Date` column, instead of dropping it, with the argument `drop=False`), get the time difference, and extract seconds with this:

```
df.set_index('Date', drop=False)['Date'].diff().apply(lambda x: x.seconds)
# Date
# 2015-03-25 12:50:37        NaN
# 2015-03-25 12:52:20      103.0
# 2015-03-25 12:52:30       10.0
```

You can then use this result to update `myseries` using the `pd.Series.update` method, which will overwrite the `NaN` values in `myseries` where the indexes match. Here is everything in one step:

```
myseries.update(df.set_index('Date', drop=False)['Date'].diff().apply(lambda x: x.seconds)
# 2015-03-25 12:52:18      NaN
# 2015-03-25 12:52:19      NaN
# 2015-03-25 12:52:20    103.0
# 2015-03-25 12:52:21      NaN
```